# python 2.7 function to convert temprature

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to write a function that converts a number from celsius to fahrenheit and I want to be able to print the result to two decimal places.

My code is:-

```
def Cel2Fah(temp): 

    temp = "28.0"

   return Cel2Fah
```

But I am not getting a result. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Where is conversion formula implemented in the function?

Comment: the formula is  temp = "((28.0*9)/5)+32" i tried it but its not showing result its blank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function never actually makes the calculation. I think you're looking for something like this:

```
def Cel2Fah(temp): 
    fah = temp * 9.0/5.0 + 32

    return fah
```

You can calculate 28C in Fahrenheit by calling the function like this:

```
Cel2Fah(28)
```

If you want to print 29C in Fahrenheit with 2 decimal places, here is ALL the code you need to run:

```
def Cel2Fah(temp): 
    fah = temp * 9.0/5.0 + 32

    return fah

print "{0:.2f}".format(Cel2Fah(29.0))
```

Comment: but the problem is that its not returning string of two decimals with 2 places i tried that with float(Cel2Fah(29.0))

Comment: @RiteshSingh You can convert it to a string with 2 decimal places by using the format function: "{0:.2f}".format(Cel2Fah(29.0))

Comment: its still not working i tried with that too

Comment: @RiteshSingh Well what's the result?

Comment: it can convert the temprature but not showing result in two digit after decimal

Comment: @RiteshSingh Did you copy the code in my first comment? What's the result of it?

Comment: yes i did bt still its not returning the value in two digit after decimal

Comment: @RiteshSingh Run the code I just added to my answer. If that doesn't work, you're doing something wrong.

Comment: i tried print earlier the problem is with the website in which i was running my code i tried on local system it worked fine Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

```
celsius = float(input('Enter degree Celsius: '))

# calculate fahrenheit
fahrenheit = (celsius * 1.8) + 32
print('%0.1f degree Celsius is equal to %0.1f degree Fahrenheit' %(celsius,fahrenheit))
```